# Understanding proof of monotonic increasing function and continuity

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, monotone-functions

I found this statement with the proof:

[image]

But I don't understand the proof. Where is the contradiction? We have a nonempty interval $J$ contained in the nonempty interval $(f(a),f(b))$. Where is the problem?

Comment: The contradiction comes in that for $y\in J$, the equation $y = f(x)$ has no solution.

Comment: Why is there no solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the above form the proof isn't done well. You know that $y_0^- < f(x_0)$ or $f(x_0) < y_0^+$. Hence at least one of the intervals $J^- = (y_0^-, f(x_0))$ and $J^+ = (f(x_0),y_0^+)$ is non-empty and does not contain any point of the form $f(x)$. This comes from the fact that $f(x_0)$ is contained in none of these intervals and $f(x) \le y_0^-$ for $x < x_0$ and $f(x) \ge y_0^+$ for $x > x_0$. W.l.o.g. assume $J^- \ne \emptyset$ and $J^- \cap f(I) = \emptyset$.

This is a contradiction: By assumption $f(I)$ is an interval which must contain  $J^-$ because $f(a) \le y_0^-$ and $y_0^+ \le f(b)$.

Comment: Of course one of the intervals is non empty. But why does it not contain any point of the form $f(x)$? And isn't $(f(a),f(b))$ always an interval, just by the definition of the notation?

Comment: I shall edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

There have been two answers, but the comments have shown that the arguments *at first glance* appeared a little obscure or cumbersome. I believe that everything is clarified now, either by enhancing the answers or by additional comments. But let us give another proof which is hopefully more transparent from the beginning.

Observe that in the theorem it is not specified whether $I$ is an open, closed or half-open interval and whether it is bounded or not. We shall prove the stronger result that $f$ is continuous on $I$.

Assume that $f$ is not continuous in a point $x_0 \in I$. Then $y_0^- < f(x_0)$ or $f(x_0) < y_0^+$. Note that only one of $y_0^\pm$ is defined if $x_0$ is a boundary point of $I$. We only consider the case $y_0^- < f(x_0)$, the other case is similar. The case under consideration can only occur when $I' = I \cap (-\infty,x_0) \ne \emptyset$. For $x < x_0$ we have $f(x) \le y_0^-$, for $x > x_0$ we have $f(x) \ge f(x_0)$. Therefore $(y_0^-,f(x_0) \cap f(I) = \emptyset$. For $\xi \in I'$ we have $f(\xi) \le y_0^-$ so that $(y_0^-,f(x_0) \subset [f(\xi),f(x_0)] \subset f(I)$ because $f(I)$ is an interval. This is the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially Paul Frost's answer, in a slighly less verbose form.

The range $f(I)$ contains the interval $(f(a),f(b))$, so every point in the interval $(f(a),f(b))$ is of the form $f(x)$ for some $x\in I$. On the other hand, only one endpoint of the non-empty interval $J$ is a value of $f$ - because $f$ jumps from $y_0^-$ to $y_0^+$. That is the contradiction.

Comment: Don't we have $f((a,b))\subseteq (f(a),f(b))$ because $f$ is monotone increasing? It loks lik you claim it the other way round? And what do you mean by endpoints of the interval? They are open...

Comment: I am assuming that $I$ is an interval containing the points $a$ and $b$. Therefore $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ are values of $f$ that belong to the range, $f(I)$. Since the range is an interval, it must contain the interval $(f(a),f(b))$. In order to prove the inclusion that you wrote down we need continuity, but we don't have it yet. Yes, the interval is open, but surely you understand what are its end points, no?

Comment: ... after all, you *are* using the notation $(a,b)$ to designate an open interval, by means of the "end points" $a,b$.